# Which point in time forms the basis for the second STO in a Journey?

Tags: journeybuilder, einstein, send-email

Here's the scenario:
I have a Journey with two consecutive newsletters. The duration time is 7 days between the two mailings. Both newsletters should be sent with the help of STO (max range 12h). The initial PushDate (schedule of the Journey) is 6:30 am.

The Question:
Let's say I get selected and pushed into Journey at 6:30 a.m.. The first STO decides that I will recive the first NL at 06:30 p.m..
What time is the basis for the STO of the second sending 7 days later? The time of the push into the Journey (06:30 a.m.) or the time of the first STO sending (06:30 p.m.).
If it is the time of the first STO, would it be theoretically possible that the sending could be on the 8 day after the first NL at 6:30 a.m.?